# Loop over the first and last image on a slideshow reactjs

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I am using this method to make a slideshow on my reactjs page without js code.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3Z780EOzIQs

It turns out that when the last image arrives, the slider container is blank and until the last image is hidden, the loop does not start again.
I wanted to know if there is a way that once it gets to the last image it will re-insert the first one (I need to add js code to it?)

App.js

```
<div class="slider">
        <div class="slide-track">
          <div class="slide">
          <StyledImg3
            src={"/config/images/image.png"}
          />
          </div>
          <div class="slide">
          <StyledImg3
            src={"/config/images/image.png"}
          />
          </div>
          <div class="slide">
          <StyledImg3
            src={"/config/images/image.png"}
          />
          </div>
          <div class="slide">
          <StyledImg3
            src={"/config/images/image.png"}
          />
          </div>
          <div class="slide">
          <StyledImg3
            src={"/config/images/image.png"}
          />
          </div>
          <div class="slide">
          <StyledImg3
            src={"/config/images/image.png"}
          />
          </div>
          <div class="slide">
          <StyledImg3
            src={"/config/images/image.png"}
          />
          </div>
          <div class="slide">
          <StyledImg3
            src={"/config/images/image.png"}
          />
          </div>
          <div class="slide">
          <StyledImg3
            src={"/config/images/image.png"}
          />
          </div>
          <div class="slide">
          <StyledImg3
            src={"/config/images/image.png"}
          />
          </div>

      </div>
      </div>
```

App.css

```
@keyframes scroll {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0)
  }

  100% {
    transform: translateX(calc(-210px*9));
  }
}

.slider {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: auto;
  width: 90%;
  height: 200px;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slide-track {
  display: flex;
  width: calc(200px*18);
  animation: scroll 30s linear infinite;
}

.slide-track:hover {
  animation-play-state: paused;
}

.slide {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 15px;
  perspective: 100px;
}
```

I tried to make an infinite slideshow but it cuts off with the last image